"Указаны конфликтующие значения параметра Signed-By" в Linux Ubuntu
При вводе sudo apt upgrade выводится:
E: Указаны конфликтующие значения параметра Signed-By из источника https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg
E: Не удалось прочитать перечень источников.

Перед этой ошибкой скачивал пакет postgresql

Выключить этот репозиторий в настройках, или закомментировать в /etc/apt/sources.list.

Я решил эту проблему так:

Зайти в папку по этому пути /etc/apt/sources.list.d
Через редактор кода войти в файл pgdg.list
Стереть код.

Буду копаться дальше, чтобы не просто устранить проблему, но и чтобы работал postgresql
